# how to check the fragment is visible to user in Xamarin Android

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin

I want to show or hide a subview in a fragment when it is shown or hidden, but no way to check the fragment is visible to user.
In android native, it seems to have a method, but Xamarin no.
Do you have any special way to get it?

I can see only a property for fragment.

```
   public override bool UserVisibleHint {
        get {
            return base.UserVisibleHint;
        }
        set {
            base.UserVisibleHint = value;
        }
    }
```

But I need a method to check this.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IsVisible` property on the `Fragment` (see: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Fragment.IsVisible/)

Additionally, you can override the [`OnHiddenChanged`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Fragment.OnHiddenChanged/p/System.Boolean/) method on your fragment class to get notified when the `Fragment`'s visibility changes

> it seems to have a method, but Xamarin no.

What method are you referring to?

Comment: Android has this override function.
@override public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) { , but Xamarin no. I need to use fragment adapter for carousel view, and when a fragment is shown up , visible to user, e.g. I hope to change its toolbar background color to red. thanks.

Comment: @CezarD. In Xamarin.Android the set/get methods from Java are converted into properties. The [`UserVisibleHint`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Fragment.UserVisibleHint/) is `virtual`, that means you can override it and call your custom code in the setter part of the property

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to check when it is changed.